# Configure LDAP over TLS to make connection be secure

Tags: ssl, certificate

I configured OpenLDAP and today I've configured the TLS for more security following these guide

```
dn: cn=config 
changetype: modify 
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile 
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ca-bundle.crt 
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile 
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/server.crt 
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile 
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/server.key...
```

but i get this error when i'm trying to LDAP modify 
-->"`bash: ldapmodify: command not found...`"

Once unfortunately i deleted the certs directory, where the key and certificate files were located. I restored them by this following method one by one
-->>"`curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`"

& /ca-bundle.trust.crt / make-dummy-cert / Makefile / renew-dummy-cert /

Then i update it by

```
update-ca-trust check
update-ca-trust enable....
```

but still it's showing me the error when i'm trying to modify

please help...

Answer (score 0):

Just *look* at the error:

> bash: ldapmodify: command not found

It's not a configuration problem; it's got nothing to do with CA certs or cn=config. It simply says that **the "ldapmodify" tool is not installed** on your computer, and you must install it.

On Fedora & CentOS, all the ldap* tools are in the `openldap-clients` package; on Debian & Ubuntu – `ldap-utils`; on Arch – `openldap`.

Comment: Thank you sir...my problem has been solved in modifying by mod_ssl.ldif.